# passing enum in C

Tags: c, types, enums, compiler-errors

This may seem like a simple question but i am getting an error when compiling this. I want to be able to pass an enum into a method in C.

Enum

```
enum TYPES { PHOTON, NEUTRINO, QUARK, PROTON, ELECTRON };
```

Calling the method

```
makeParticle(PHOTON, 0.3f, 0.09f, location, colour);
```

Method

```
struct Particle makeParticle(enum TYPES type, float radius, float speed, struct Vector3 location, struct Vector3 colour)
{
    struct Particle p;
    p.type = type;
    p.radius = radius;
    p.speed = speed;
    p.location = location;
    p.colour = colour;

    return p;
}
```

The error I am getting is when I am calling the method:

> incompatible types in assignment

Comment: For what it's worth, most people call them "functions" rather than "methods," but we all know what you're talking about.

Comment: One of the greatest things about compiler errors is that they usually include a line number. Which line gave you an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compiles fine for me, in this cut-down example:

```
enum TYPES { PHOTON, NEUTRINO, QUARK, PROTON, ELECTRON };

void makeParticle(enum TYPES type)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    makeParticle(PHOTON);
}
```

Are you sure that you've made the declaration of `TYPES` available to the code in both the definition of `makeParticle` and the call to it?  It won't work if you do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    makeParticle(PHOTON);
}

enum TYPES { PHOTON, NEUTRINO, QUARK, PROTON, ELECTRON };

void makeParticle(enum TYPES type)
{
}
```

because the `main()` code hasn't seen TYPES yet.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
p.type = type;
```

to

```
p.type = (int)type;
```

If this doesn't help, please add the whole .c file, including the definition of `struct Particle` to your question.